# ActionView::Template::Error (960.css isn't precompiled)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, actionview, asset-pipeline

I have an iframe which renders a partial and is not part of the main application layout or asset pipeline.

I'd like to include some style sheets, however I am getting this error:

```
 ActionView::Template::Error (960sm.css isn't precompiled):
```

Rails 3.1
Heroku

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Style sheets that are not included in a manifest (directly by name or indirectly via require_tree) are not precompiled, so will not accessible in production.

You need to add the sheet to the list of items to precompile in the environment application.rb.

```
config.assets.precompile += ['960sm.css']
```

And then access it in the view:

```
stylesheet_link_tag('960sm')
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me sort out the asset pipeline.

Comment: Works fine, helped me a lot, but the description on application.css gives another idea about how it works: ... /*
 * This is a manifest file that'll automatically include all the stylesheets available in this directory
 * and any sub-directories. You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at
 * the top of the compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree . 
*/

Comment: this helped me...after a few hrs of finding a solution

Comment: After you changed all the config file needed to make it works... YOU MUST run touch YOURAPPDIR/tmp/restart.txt to refresh Pasenger cache

Answer (score 4):

Instead of managing a list of CSS files, you may prefer to simply adjust the extension by adding .scss to the filename.

Hence, *960sm.css* would become *960sm.css.scss*.

This should not break anything as valid CSS is valid SCSS.

Comment: That's fine but remember *not* to add .scss in the precompile list. "Always specify an [expected compiled filename that ends with .js or .css](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets), even if you want to add Sass or CoffeeScript files to the precompile array."

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of standalone assets, then instead of adding each one to the list, like this

```
config.assets.precompile += ['960sm.css']
```

you may want to just precompile *everything*, like this:

```
def precompile?(path)
  %w(app lib vendor).each do |asset_root|
    assets_path = Rails.root.join(asset_root, 'assets').to_path
    return true if path.starts_with?(assets_path)
  end
  false
end

# Precompile all assets under app/assets (unless they start with _)
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile << proc do |name, path|
  starts_with_underscore = name.split('/').last.starts_with?('_')
  unless starts_with_underscore
    path = Rails.application.assets.resolve(name).to_path unless path # Rails 4 passes path; Rails 3 doesn't
    precompile?(path)
  end
end
```

(Based on the [code in the Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets).)