# heroku error when deploying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my exercise web app onto heroku, but what I only get is the heroku generic error "we're sorry, but something went wrong.".

my web app url is something like "http://myappdomain.heroku.com/microposts"

so, I went to the heroku logs, and here what I got:

```
←[36m2011-11-01T00:17:17+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     2: <html>
←[36m2011-11-01T00:17:17+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     3: <head>
←[36m2011-11-01T00:17:17+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     4:   <title>DemoApp</title>
←[36m2011-11-01T00:17:17+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag
   "application" %>
←[36m2011-11-01T00:17:17+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     6:   <%= javascript_include_t
ag "application" %>
←[36m2011-11-01T00:17:17+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
←[36m2011-11-01T00:17:17+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     8: </head>
←[36m2011-11-01T00:17:17+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   app/views/layouts/application.h
tml.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__208214517728482137_320580
20'
←[36m2011-11-01T00:17:17+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   app/controllers/microposts_cont
roller.rb:7:in `index'
←[36m2011-11-01T00:17:17+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2011-11-01T00:17:17+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2011-11-01T00:17:17+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m cache: [GET /microposts] miss
←[36m2011-11-01T00:17:29+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2011-11-01T00:17:29+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2011-11-01T00:17:29+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Started GET "/assets/rails.png" f
or 110.171.180.34 at 2011-10-31 17:17:29 -0700
←[36m2011-11-01T00:17:29+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2011-11-01T00:17:29+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m ActionController::RoutingError (N
o route matches [GET] "/assets/rails.png"):
←[36m2011-11-01T00:17:29+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2011-11-01T00:17:29+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2011-11-01T00:17:29+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2011-11-01T00:17:29+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m cache: [GET /assets/rails.png] mi
ss
←[33m2011-11-01T00:17:29+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m GET grisly-flower-7610.heroku
.com/assets/rails.png dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=10ms status=404 bytes=
728
←[36m2011-11-01T00:17:38+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2011-11-01T00:17:38+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2011-11-01T00:17:38+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Started GET "/users" for 10.10.10
.60 at 2011-10-31 17:17:38 -0700
←[36m2011-11-01T00:17:38+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Processing by UsersController#i
ndex as HTML
←[36m2011-11-01T00:17:38+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Rendered users/index.html.erb wit
hin layouts/application (0.8ms)
←[36m2011-11-01T00:17:38+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Completed 500 Internal Server Err
or in 34ms
←[36m2011-11-01T00:17:38+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2011-11-01T00:17:38+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m ActionView::Template::Error (appl
ication.css isn't precompiled):
←[36m2011-11-01T00:17:38+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     2: <html>
←[36m2011-11-01T00:17:38+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     3: <head>
←[36m2011-11-01T00:17:38+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     4:   <title>DemoApp</title>
←[36m2011-11-01T00:17:38+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag
   "application" %>
←[36m2011-11-01T00:17:38+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     6:   <%= javascript_include_t
ag "application" %>
←[36m2011-11-01T00:17:38+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
←[36m2011-11-01T00:17:38+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     8: </head>
←[36m2011-11-01T00:17:38+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   app/views/layouts/application.h
tml.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__208214517728482137_320580
20'
←[36m2011-11-01T00:17:38+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   app/controllers/users_controlle
r.rb:7:in `index'
←[36m2011-11-01T00:17:38+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2011-11-01T00:17:38+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2011-11-01T00:17:38+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m cache: [GET /users] miss
←[33m2011-11-01T00:17:38+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m GET grisly-flower-7610.heroku
.com/users dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=43ms status=500 bytes=728
←[32m2011-11-01T00:17:38+00:00 heroku[nginx]:←[0m 110.171.180.34 - - [31/Oct/201
1:17:17:38 -0700] "GET /users HTTP/1.0" 500 728 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0
) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.106 Safari/535.2" grisly
-flower-7610.heroku.com
←[36m2011-11-01T00:17:46+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2011-11-01T00:17:46+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2011-11-01T00:17:46+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Started GET "/rails/info/properti
es" for 10.10.10.60 at 2011-10-31 17:17:46 -0700
←[36m2011-11-01T00:17:46+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2011-11-01T00:17:46+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m ActionController::RoutingError (N
o route matches [GET] "/rails/info/properties"):
←[36m2011-11-01T00:17:46+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2011-11-01T00:17:46+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2011-11-01T00:17:46+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2011-11-01T00:17:46+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m cache: [GET /rails/info/propertie
s] miss
←[33m2011-11-01T00:17:46+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m GET grisly-flower-7610.heroku
.com/rails/info/properties dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=15ms status=404 b
ytes=728
←[32m2011-11-01T00:17:46+00:00 heroku[nginx]:←[0m 110.171.180.34 - - [31/Oct/201
1:17:17:46 -0700] "GET /rails/info/properties HTTP/1.0" 404 728 "http://grisly-f
lower-7610.heroku.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML,
like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.106 Safari/535.2" grisly-flower-7610.heroku.com
←[36m2011-11-01T00:17:51+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2011-11-01T00:17:51+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2011-11-01T00:17:51+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Started GET "/rails/info/properti
es" for 10.10.10.60 at 2011-10-31 17:17:51 -0700
←[36m2011-11-01T00:17:51+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2011-11-01T00:17:51+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2011-11-01T00:17:51+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m ActionController::RoutingError (N
o route matches [GET] "/rails/info/properties"):
←[36m2011-11-01T00:17:51+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2011-11-01T00:17:51+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2011-11-01T00:17:51+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m cache: [GET /rails/info/propertie
s] miss
←[33m2011-11-01T00:17:51+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m GET grisly-flower-7610.heroku
.com/rails/info/properties dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=7ms status=404 by
tes=728
←[32m2011-11-01T00:17:51+00:00 heroku[nginx]:←[0m 110.171.180.34 - - [31/Oct/201
1:17:17:51 -0700] "GET /rails/info/properties HTTP/1.0" 404 728 "http://grisly-f
lower-7610.heroku.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML,
like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.106 Safari/535.2" grisly-flower-7610.heroku.com
←[33m2011-11-01T00:18:00+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m GET grisly-flower-7610.heroku
.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=6ms status=200 bytes=5907
←[36m2011-11-01T00:18:06+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2011-11-01T00:18:06+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2011-11-01T00:18:06+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Started GET "/microposts" for 10.
10.10.60 at 2011-10-31 17:18:06 -0700
←[36m2011-11-01T00:18:06+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Processing by MicropostsControl
ler#index as HTML
←[35m←[0m
←[36m0:18:06+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Rendered microposts/index.html.erb within lay
outs/application (0.3ms)
←[36m2011-11-01T00:18:06+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Completed 500 Internal Server Err
or in 4ms
←[36m2011-11-01T00:18:06+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2011-11-01T00:18:06+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m ActionView::Template::Error (appl
ication.css isn't precompiled):
←[36m2011-11-01T00:18:06+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     2: <html>
←[36m2011-11-01T00:18:06+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     4:   <title>DemoApp</title>
←[36m2011-11-01T00:18:06+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     3: <head>
←[36m2011-11-01T00:18:06+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag
   "application" %>
←[36m2011-11-01T00:18:06+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     6:   <%= javascript_include_t
ag "application" %>
←[36m2011-11-01T00:18:06+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
←[36m2011-11-01T00:18:06+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     8: </head>
←[36m2011-11-01T00:18:06+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   app/views/layouts/application.h
tml.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__208214517728482137_320580
20'
←[36m2011-11-01T00:18:06+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   app/controllers/microposts_cont
roller.rb:7:in `index'
←[36m2011-11-01T00:18:06+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2011-11-01T00:18:06+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2011-11-01T00:18:06+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m cache: [GET /microposts] miss
←[32m2011-11-01T00:18:06+00:00 heroku[nginx]:←[0m 110.171.180.34 - - [31/Oct/201
1:17:18:06 -0700] "GET /microposts HTTP/1.0" 500 728 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows N
T 6.0) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.106 Safari/535.2" g
risly-flower-7610.heroku.com
←[36m2011-11-01T00:21:35+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2011-11-01T00:21:35+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2011-11-01T00:21:35+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Started GET "/microposts" for 10.
10.10.60 at 2011-10-31 17:21:35 -0700
←[36m2011-11-01T00:21:35+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Processing by MicropostsControl
ler#index as HTML
←[36m2011-11-01T00:21:35+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Rendered microposts/index.html.er
b within layouts/application (0.3ms)
←[36m2011-11-01T00:21:35+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   app/controllers/microposts_cont
roller.rb:7:in `index'
←[36m2011-11-01T00:21:35+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2011-11-01T00:21:35+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   app/views/layouts/application.h
tml.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__208214517728482137_320580
20'
←[36m2011-11-01T00:21:35+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2011-11-01T00:21:35+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[33m2011-11-01T00:21:35+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m GET grisly-flower-7610.heroku
.com/microposts dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=55ms status=500 bytes=728
←[33m2011-11-01T00:23:14+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m GET grisly-flower-7610.heroku
.com/assets/rails.png dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=6ms status=404 bytes=7
28
```

any advice would be really appreciated to get it working.

Comment: Looks like you didn't precompile your assets: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails31_heroku_cedar

Comment: possible duplicate of [ActionView::Template::Error (960.css isn't precompiled)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577236/actionviewtemplateerror-960-css-isnt-precompiled)

Comment: it's working gracefully just now!

Answer (score 0):

If you deployed your application to the Cedar stack then you wouldn't have to precompile. Looks like you're running on the Bamboo stack.