# Rails assets pipeline: not precompiled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ActionView::Template::Error (960.css isn’t precompiled)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577236/actionviewtemplateerror-960-css-isnt-precompiled)

I'm getting this error when running the app in production:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (custom.css isn't precompiled):
```

I've run rake assets:precompile, but this doesn't help. In the console I can see that custom.css is compiled:

```
me@server:/webapps/myapp/current# rake assets:precompile
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
...
Compiled custom.css  (629ms)  (pid 17716)
Compiled responsive.css  (0ms)  (pid 17716)
Compiled iphone_checkbox_style.css  (30ms)  (pid 17716)
...
```

I'm running Rails 3.2.2 app on Ubuntu server with Nginx and Passenger.

config/enrivonments/production.rb is configured to have this:

```
config.assets.compile = false
```

I sort of running out of ideas what could possible go wrong. Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: `config.assets.compile = true` should fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You could either add it to your precompile list, like so:

```
config.assets.precompile += ['custom.css']
```

or rename it, like so:

```
custom.css.scss
```

Comment: make sure you don't have custom.scss but rather custom.css.scss as mentioned!